# Android Multiple Buttons with Different Layout Placement using FrameLayout xml

Tags: android, xml, button, mobile, imagebutton

I'm new to Android.

I'm playing with landscape view. I have text in the center of the screen. I have two buttons (False and True) directly below the text and then I am trying to have a previous image button on the very bottom left of the screen and a next image button on the very bottom right of the screen.

The problem is that with the multiple layouts in FrameLayout, I'm unable to get the next and previous buttons to separate and be on opposite corners of the bottom of the screen.

How may I modify the XML gravity-layout attribute to do this? I keep getting both of the image buttons stuck next to each on on the very left side.

[Current Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz4pF.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:contentDescription="@string/prev_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageButton`s are children of a `LinearLayout`. `LinearLayout` never uses all of the available space if you don't use the attribute `android:layout_weight` on some of the child `View`s. I won't explain here how to do this because it's better for performance to drop the `LinearLayout` and let the `ImageButton`s be children of the `FrameLayout`:

```
</FrameLayout>

   <!-- other Views like before ... -->

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/prev_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

</FrameLayout>
```